# How to make python Tkinter code a program file, not just a downloadable .exe?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've made a downloadable exe using auto-py-to-exe, but I want an actual application that can be downloaded as an app (such as Chrome). Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to make the .exe download the app, like most apps do? Should I even be using Tkinter for this, or should I use something different - if so, what?

EDIT: How to run an installer, and have it put an icon of my tkinter program in the start menu or on the desktop?

Comment: What do you mean when you say program file?

Comment: An application that runs on a Windows PC is an .exe. It's also known as a program. Are you asking about specifically making the program a Microsoft Store app? Or you just want to run an installer, and have it put an icon of your program in the start menu or on the desktop, as well as having an entry in the "add/remove programs" section of the Control Panel? I think you're not clear on the terminology you're using. Google Chrome is a .exe. When you download it, you download an installer (which is either a .exe or .msi usually), which then puts the final program's .exe in your `Program Files`.

Comment: "Or you just want to run an installer, and have it put an icon of your program in the start menu or on the desktop?" This pretty much sums it up! How do I do this? @RandomDavis

Comment: This is not a Python-specific thing. if you have your program as a .exe already, then you don't need to do anything else with Python. There are plenty of resources online already for how to make an installer for a .exe, including one that puts in all the registry entries, icons, shortcuts, etc. If you search "how to make a program installer on windows" there's over 5 million results. I doubt that you'll need any more help from us once you try searching for that.